# Python IMAP login bruteforcer

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

Below is the code of a command line tool built with Python that will download email via IMAP.

Omitted from the code below are 2 important functions `parse_line` and `server_login`.

`parse_line` takes a string containing data and returns the email and password from that string as a dictionary.
`server_login` tries to log in to the IMAP server with the supplied credentials. It changes the default socket timeout, so any code you see below related to socket timeouts is related to this function.

**Note: these functions can be found in the github repository if someone needs them to better understand the code, but I'd rather people focus on just the provided code.**

Here is a link to the complete program: [https://github.com/choket/imap-email-downloader](https://github.com/choket/imap-email-downloader/tree/8d12fcddafa55a8fb3b3435c64fa67ed4252e9c3)
Any feedback related to the github project is also welcome.

The purpose if this program is to be used as a command line utility, as well as being easily integrable into other python projects.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# MIT License https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
#
# Copyright (c) 2019 Stefan Stojanovski https://github.com/choket

# WEIRD INDEXES EXPLANATION:
# imaplib's fetch() command returns the server response in a weirdly formatted way.
# It returns a tuple containing the server's response status and response data.
# Then additionally, the response data is actually a list containing some metadata and the data itself.
# So, depending on what data was fetch()'ed, we need to dig through the response accordingly to find the actual data

import argparse
import base64
import imaplib
import os
import re
import socket
import sys
import time
from typing import Union, Optional

from parse_line import parse_line
from server_login import server_login, email_scraper_errors, login_error, connection_error


class server_error(email_scraper_errors):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message


def _count_lines(
        filename: str
):
    """
    Returns number of lines in a file in an optimized way. Useful for big files

    :param filename: Path to file
    :return: Number of lines
    :raise IOError: If the file couldn't be opened
    """
    lines = 0
    buf_size = 1024 * 1024

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        read_content = f.read(buf_size)
        while read_content:
            lines += read_content.count(b"\n")
            read_content = f.read(buf_size)

    return lines


def _download_email_attachments(
        server: Union[imaplib.IMAP4, imaplib.IMAP4_SSL],
        email_number: str,
        output_dir: Optional[str] = "attachments"
):
    """Download the attachments of an email

    :param server: imaplib object which is logged in and has a mailbox selected
    :param email_number: Number of the email whose attachments to download
    :param output_dir: Directory where to output the attachments
    :return: None
    """
    # output_dir is converted to bytes so that the attachment name, which is bytes, can be appended to it
    output_dir = bytes(output_dir, encoding="utf-8")

    status, body_structure = server.fetch(email_number, "(BODYSTRUCTURE)")

    # See comment at start of file for explanation about the indexes
    body_structure = body_structure[0]

    # body_structure has the attachment filenames in the form of(including quotes): <other_data> ("attachment" ("filename" "<filename>" <other_data>
    # This is a relatively primitive way to search for the attachment filenames
    filename_pattern = re.compile(rb'\("attachment" \("filename" "(.+?)"')

    found_attachments = filename_pattern.findall(body_structure)

    num_attachments = len(found_attachments)

    for i, attachment_name in enumerate(found_attachments, 1):
        charset = "utf-8"

        # Check if attachment name contains non utf-8 characters
        if attachment_name.startswith(b"=?"):

            # The attachment name can consist of multiple sections each encoded with different charsets
            attachment_section_pattern = re.compile(rb"=\?(.+?)\?=(?: |$)")
            attachment_name_sections = attachment_section_pattern.findall(attachment_name)

            attachment_name = b""
            for attachment_name_section in attachment_name_sections:
                charset, encoding_type, attachment_name_part = attachment_name_section.decode().split("?")
                attachment_name_part = bytes(attachment_name_part, encoding="utf-8")

                # attachment_name_part will either be Base64 or Query string encoded

                # Base64 encoding
                if encoding_type == "B":
                    attachment_name += base64.b64decode(attachment_name_part)

                # Query string encoding, where non utf-8 bytes are encoded as their hexadecimal value, prepended by an "=" sign, for example: =D3
                elif encoding_type == "Q":
                    # Function that will convert the hex value from the regex search to a byte
                    hex_to_byte = lambda regex_match: bytes.fromhex(regex_match.group(1).decode())

                    attachment_name += re.sub(rb"=([0-9A-F]{2})", hex_to_byte, attachment_name_part)

        status, attachment_data_container = server.fetch(email_number, "(BODY[{}])".format(i + 1))

        # TODO Check if response == "OK"

        # See comment at start of file for explanation about the indexes
        attachment_data_b64 = attachment_data_container[0][1]
        attachment_raw_data = base64.b64decode(attachment_data_b64)

        # Replace invalid filename characters underscores
        for char in (b">", b"<", b":", b"\"", b"/", b"\\", b"|", b"?", b"*"):
            if char in attachment_name:
                attachment_name = attachment_name.replace(char, b"_")

        try:
            os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
        except PermissionError:
            raise PermissionError("Could not create {}, invalid permissions".format(output_dir))

        output_location = os.path.join(output_dir, attachment_name).decode(charset, errors="ignore")
        try:
            attachment_file = open(output_location, "wb")
        except IOError as e:
            sys.stderr.write("Could not write to attachment file. Reason:" + str(e) + "\n")
        else:
            with attachment_file:
                attachment_file.write(attachment_raw_data)

    return num_attachments


def scrape_emails(
        server: Union[imaplib.IMAP4, imaplib.IMAP4_SSL],
        mark_as_read: Optional[bool] = False,
        email_parts: Optional[str] = "all",
        start_mailbox: Optional[int] = 1,
        start_email: Optional[int] = 1,
        output_dir: Optional[str] = None,
        verbosity_level: Optional[int] = 2
):
    """Download all the emails in an email account via IMAP access

    :param server: imaplib object which is logged in, and has the username or email used to log in set in custom attribute called "username_or_email"
    :param mark_as_read: When set to True, the script will mark all the emails it downloads as Read in the IMAP server
    :param email_parts: What parts of the email to download. Options are:
        "headers" or "metadata": Email headers.
        "body"            : Email body.
        "no-attachments"  : Email headers + body without attachments.
        "attachments"     : Just the email attachments.
        "all"             : Entire email.
    :param start_mailbox: Number of mailbox from which to start downloading emails, effectively skipping all previous ones
    :param start_email: Number of email in the mailbox from which to start downloading, effectively skipping all previous ones
    :param output_dir: Directory where to output the downloaded email.
        A folder will be created for each mailbox and the emails of that mailbox will be placed there
    :param verbosity_level: Available levels are:
        0) No messages are printed
        1) A message is printed for each user
        2) A message is printed for each mailbox in the user's account
    :return: None
    """
    # TODO If mark_as_read is set to True, ask the user for confirmation

    # Classes used to catch imaplib exceptions
    imap_server_errors = (imaplib.IMAP4.error, imaplib.IMAP4_SSL.error)

    # username_or_email is a custom property of imaplib's object that is set when logging in in server_login() function
    username_or_email = server.username_or_email

    if "@" in username_or_email:
        username = username_or_email.split("@")[0]
    else:
        username = username_or_email

    host = server.host

    if output_dir is None:
        output_dir = host

    if verbosity_level >= 1:
        sys.stdout.write("Downloading emails of {}\n".format(username))

    # Reset the connection timeout back to default value, now that we are already logged in
    # When initially connecting to a server, the timeout is set to a low value, around 1 second
    server.sock.settimeout(15)

    try:
        response, mailboxes = server.list()
    except imap_server_errors:
        raise server_error("Error getting mailboxes from server")

    if response != "OK":
        raise server_error("Error getting mailboxes from server")

    num_mailboxes = len(mailboxes)

    # Decide what parts of the email to download, based on the IMAP rfc
    if email_parts == "all":
        imap_email_parts = "BODY[]"
    elif email_parts == "headers" or email_parts == "metadata":
        # TODO Check if this contains a boundary start as the last line
        imap_email_parts = "BODY[HEADER]"
    elif email_parts == "body":
        # TODO This also downloads attachments. Change it so it only downloads the body
        imap_email_parts = "BODY[TEXT]"
    elif email_parts == "attachments":
        # Downloading email attachments is handled below at the server.fetch() line
        pass
    else:
        sys.stderr.write("Invalid parts to download, defaulting to all!\n")
        imap_email_parts = "BODY[]"

    for i_mailbox, imap_mailbox in enumerate(mailboxes, 1):
        # Skip to the mailbox specified in start_mailbox
        if i_mailbox < start_mailbox:
            continue

        # Extract the name of the mailbox from the server response
        if '"/"' in imap_mailbox.decode(errors="replace"):
            mailbox_name = imap_mailbox.decode(errors="replace").split('"/" ')[-1]
        else:
            mailbox_name = imap_mailbox.decode(errors="replace").split("NIL ")[-1]

        response, num_emails_data = server.select(mailbox_name, readonly=not mark_as_read)

        if response != "OK":
            msg = "\t({}/{}) Error selecting mailbox {} | Reason: {}\n".format(i_mailbox, num_mailboxes, imap_mailbox.decode(errors="replace"), num_emails_data[0].decode(errors="replace"))
            sys.stdout.write(msg)
            # raise server_error(msg)
            continue

        # See comment at start of file for explanation about the indexes
        num_emails = int(num_emails_data[0].decode())

        # Replace invalid filename characters with underscores
        for char in (">", "<", ":", "\"", "/", "\\", "|", "?", "*"):
            if char in mailbox_name:
                mailbox_name = mailbox_name.replace(char, "_")


        if output_dir != "":
            mailbox_output_directory = os.path.join(output_dir, mailbox_name)
        else:
            mailbox_output_directory = mailbox_name


        try:
            os.makedirs(mailbox_output_directory, exist_ok=True)
        except PermissionError:
            raise PermissionError("Could not create {}, invalid permissions".format(mailbox_output_directory))

        response, emails_data = server.search(None, "ALL")

        if response != "OK":
            msg = "Error searching for emails in mailbox: {}\n".format(imap_mailbox.decode(errors="replace"))
            sys.stderr.write(msg)
            # raise server_error(msg)
            continue

        # See comment at start of file for explanation about the indexes
        emails = emails_data[0].decode().split()

        for i in emails:
            # Skip to the email specified in start_email
            if int(i) < start_email:
                continue

            if verbosity_level == 2:
                sys.stdout.write("\t({}/{}) Downloading mailbox: {} | {} Total emails | ({}/{})\r".format(str(i_mailbox).zfill(len(str(num_mailboxes))), num_mailboxes, mailbox_name, num_emails, i, num_emails))
                sys.stdout.flush()

            if email_parts == "attachments":
                num_attachments = _download_email_attachments(server=server, email_number=i, output_dir=os.path.join(output_dir, mailbox_name, i))
                continue

            try:
                response, fetched_parts = server.fetch(i, "(FLAGS {})".format(imap_email_parts))
            except imap_server_errors as e:
                msg = "\nError downloading email {}\n".format(i)
                sys.stderr.write(msg)
                # raise server_error(msg)
                continue

            if response != "OK":
                msg = "\nError downloading email {}\n".format(i)
                sys.stderr.write(msg)
                # raise server_error(msg)
                continue

            email_contents = b""
            # The last part in fetched_parts is ")", so skip it
            for part in fetched_parts[:-1]:
                email_contents += part[1]

            email_read_status = "READ" if "SEEN" in fetched_parts[0][0].decode().upper() else "UNREAD"
            email_filename = i + "-" + email_read_status + ".eml"
            email_file_path = os.path.join(mailbox_output_directory, email_filename)

            with open(email_file_path, "wb") as email_file:
                email_file.write(email_contents)
        else:
            # Check if there are no emails in mailbox
            if not emails and verbosity_level == 2:
                sys.stdout.write("\t({}/{}) Downloading mailbox: {} | {} Total emails | ({}/{})\r".format(str(i_mailbox).zfill(len(str(num_mailboxes))), num_mailboxes, mailbox_name, 0, 0, 0))
                sys.stdout.flush()

            if verbosity_level == 2:
                # Print newline to compensate for the last \r
                sys.stdout.write("\n")


def batch_scrape(
        file: str,
        host: Optional[str] = None,
        port: Optional[int] = None,
        use_ssl: Optional[bool] = False,
        login_only: Optional[bool] = False,
        file_delimiter: Optional[str] = ":",
        start_line: Optional[int] = 1,
        try_common_hosts: Optional[bool] = False,
        mark_as_read: Optional[bool] = False,
        email_parts: Optional[str] = "all",
        output_dir: Optional[str] = None,
        timeout: Optional[Union[float, int]] = 1.0,
        verbosity_level: Optional[int] = 2
):
    """Download all the emails of multiple email accounts written in a file via IMAP. Downloaded emails are saved under `output_dir/username/mailbox_name/`

    :param file:
        A file containing login credentials in the form of `username:password`
        or `username@example.com:password` separated by newlines.
        You can specify a custom delimiter instead of `:` by using the file_delimiter parameter
    :param host: IP or domain of the IMAP server
    :param port: Port on which the IMAP server is listening
    :param use_ssl: Use SSL when connecting to the server
    :param login_only: Don't download any emails, just log in and write the valid credentials to the output file or stdout if no output file is given
    :param file_delimiter: Delimiter which separates the email from the password in the input file
    :param start_line: Line number from which to start parsing the input file, effectively skipping all previous ones
    :param try_common_hosts: If connecting to host fails, try connecting to common subdomains of the host on which the server might be running
    :param mark_as_read: When set to True, the script will mark all the emails it downloads as Read in the IMAP server
    :param email_parts: What parts of the email to download. Options are:
        "headers" or "metadata": Email headers.
        "body"            : Email body.
        "no-attachments"  : Email headers + body without attachments.
        "attachments"     : Just the email attachments.
        "all"             : Entire email.
    :param output_dir: Directory where to output the downloaded email.
        A folder will be created for each mailbox and the emails of that mailbox will be placed there
    :param timeout: Maximum number of seconds to try and establish a connection
    :param verbosity_level: Available levels are:
        0) No messages are printed
        1) A message is printed for each user
        2) A message is printed for each mailbox in the user's account
    :return:
    """
    invalid_hosts = set()
    valid_hosts = set()

    try:
        num_lines = _count_lines(file)
    except IOError:
        num_lines = 0

    original_host = host
    # offset by -1 to skip TO N-th line instead of skipping N lines
    start_line -= 1

    try:
        credentials_file = open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
    except IOError as e:
        sys.stderr.write("Could not open input file. Reason:" + str(e) + "\n")
    else:
        with credentials_file:
            # Skip to the line specified in start_line
            for _ in range(start_line):
                next(credentials_file)

            for i, line in enumerate(credentials_file, 1):

                credentials = parse_line(line, delimiter=file_delimiter)

                # parse_line() function returns None if it couldn't find any credentials in the line specified
                if credentials is None:
                    continue

                if original_host is None:
                    try:
                        host = credentials["email"].split("@")[1].lower()
                    except IndexError:
                        continue
                else:
                    host = original_host.lower()

                # TODO Remove this and use the try_common_hosts parameter of server_login
                if try_common_hosts:
                    # Additional hosts to be used if connecting to the original one fails
                    # IMAP servers can be commonly found on specific subdomains, not the actual domain
                    possible_hosts = (host, "imap." + host, "mail." + host)
                else:
                    possible_hosts = (host, )

                for test_host in possible_hosts:

                    # Skip connecting to the host if it is invalid_hosts, but also specifically check whether it is NOT in valid_hosts.
                    # Even if the IMAP server works as expected, sometimes it can bug out and produce a connection error.
                    # That connection error will cause the host to be added to invalid_hosts, even though it works normally.
                    # So, when successfully connecting to a server we add that server to valid_hosts to make sure it doesn't get skipped
                    if test_host in invalid_hosts and test_host not in valid_hosts:
                        continue

                    if verbosity_level >= 1:
                        # Pad the line index to be the same width as the total number of lines
                        sys.stdout.write("({}/{}) | ".format(str(i + start_line).zfill(len(str(num_lines))), num_lines))
                        sys.stdout.flush()

                    # Connect to the server
                    try:
                        server_connection = server_login(
                            user_or_email_or_combo=credentials["email"],
                            password=credentials["password"],
                            host=test_host,
                            port=port,
                            use_ssl=use_ssl,
                            timeout=timeout
                        )
                    except connection_error as error:
                        # Could not connect to host
                        if verbosity_level >= 1:
                            sys.stdout.write(str(error) + "\n")

                        if error.host not in valid_hosts:
                            invalid_hosts.add(error.host)

                        continue
                    except login_error as error:
                        # Invalid login details

                        if verbosity_level >= 1:
                            sys.stdout.write(str(error) + "\n")

                        break
                    except Exception as e:
                        # Catch any unhandled exceptions and write them to a log file
                        # The script should continue parsing the credentials file until the end, regardless if an exception happened
                        msg = "An unhandled exception occurred at line {}:\n{}\n".format(i + start_line, str(e))
                        sys.stderr.write(msg)

                        with open(os.path.join(output_dir, "error_log.txt"), "a") as log:
                            log.write(msg + "\n")

                        break
                    else:
                        valid_hosts.add(test_host)

                        if login_only:
                            if verbosity_level >= 1:
                                sys.stdout.write("Valid credentials: " + credentials["email"] + file_delimiter + credentials["password"] + "\n")

                            try:
                                output_file = open(output_dir, "a")
                            except IOError as e:
                                sys.stderr.write("Could not open output file. Reason:" + str(e) + "\n")
                            else:
                                with output_file:
                                    output_file.write(credentials["email"] + file_delimiter + credentials["password"] + "\n")

                            break


                    # Download the emails
                    try:
                        scrape_emails(
                            server=server_connection,
                            mark_as_read=mark_as_read,
                            email_parts=email_parts,
                            output_dir=os.path.join(output_dir, test_host, credentials["username"]),
                            verbosity_level=verbosity_level
                        )
                    except (server_error, PermissionError) as error:
                        sys.stderr.write(str(error) + "\n")

                    break


def main():
    program_description = "Download all emails from an email account on an IMAP server and save the raw email contents to disk\n"
    program_description += "Downloaded emails are saved under `output_dir/username/mailbox_name/"

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=program_description, formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter, add_help=False)

    credentials_args = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)


    credentials_args.add_argument("-u", "--user", "--username", dest="username",
                                    help="Username or complete credentials.\n" +
                                        "The username can either be the full email: `bob@example.com` or just the username: `bob`\n" +
                                        "Or it can contain the email address and password, separated by `:`\n" +
                                        "along with other data commonly found in database dumps\n\n")
    ap.add_argument("-p", "--pass", "--password", dest="password",
                            help="Password. If omitted you will be prompted to enter it when connecting to the server\n\n")

    credentials_args.add_argument("-f", "--file",
                                    help="Credentials file.\n" +
                                        "A file containing login credentials in the form of `username:password`\n" +
                                        "or `username@example.com:password` separated by newlines\n" +
                                        "You can specify a custom delimiter instead of `:` by using the -d option\n\n")
    ap.add_argument("-d", "--delimiter", "--file-delimiter", dest="file_delimiter", default=":",
                            help="The character which separates the username and password in the credentials file\n\n")

    ap.add_argument("-h", "--host", dest="host",
                            help="IP or full domain name of the IMAP server\n\n")

    ap.add_argument("-P", "--port",
                            help="Port on which the IMAP server is listening. Default is 143 (or 993 if -s is used)\n\n")

    ap.add_argument("-c", "--common-hosts", dest="common_hosts", action="store_true",
                            help="If connecting to host fails, try subdomains such as mail.example.com and imap.example.com\n\n")

    ap.add_argument("-s", "--ssl", action="store_true",
                            help="Use SSL when connecting to the server\n\n")

    ap.add_argument("-t", "--timeout", default=1.0,
                            help="Timeout to be used when connecting to the server (in seconds).\n" +
                                "Default is 1.\n" +
                                "Anything below 0.5 will result in false-negatives, depending on the server.\n" +
                                "If using a proxy, specify a higher timeout than normally.\n\n")

    ap.add_argument("-L", "--line", "--start-line", dest="start_line", default=1,
                            help="Start parsing the credentials file from the N-th line. (Skip the first N-1 lines)\n\n")
    ap.add_argument("-M", "--mailbox", "--start-mailbox", dest="start_mailbox", default=1,
                            help="Start downloading emails from the N-th mailbox. (Skip the first N-1 mailboxes)\n\n")
    ap.add_argument("-E", "--email", "--start-email", dest="start_email", default=1,
                            help="Start downloading emails from the N-th email in the mailbox. (Skip the first N-1 emails)\n\n")

    ap.add_argument("-r", "--mark-as-read", action="store_true",
                            help="Use this option to mark the emails as read when downloading them.\n" +
                                "Default is to NOT mark them as read\n\n")
    ap.add_argument("-l", "--login-only", action="store_true",
                            help="Just check whether the username and password are valid and don't download any emails\n\n")
    ap.add_argument("--parts", "--email-parts", choices=("headers", "metadata", "body", "no-attachments", "attachments", "all"), default="all",
                            help="Specify what parts of the email to download. Options are:\n" +
                                "headers|metadata: Email headers\n" +
                                "body            : Email body\n" +
                                "attachments     : Just the email attachments\n" +
                                "all             : Entire email\n\n")
    ap.add_argument("-o", "--output-dir",
                            help="Output directory (relative or absolute). Defaults to the same value as `host`.\n" +
                                "Pass an empty string to download emails to the current working directory\n\n")
    ap.add_argument("-v", "--verbosity-level", choices=("0", "1", "2"), default="2",
                            help="Verbosity level. Default level is 2. Available levels are:\n" +
                                "0) No messages are printed\n" +
                                "1) A message is printed for each user\n" +
                                "2) A message is printed for each mailbox in the user's account\n")

    ap.add_argument("--help", action="help", help="Show a help message along with usage info")

    args = ap.parse_args()
    username = args.username
    password = args.password
    host = args.host
    try_common_hosts = args.common_hosts
    credentials_file = args.file
    file_delimiter = args.file_delimiter
    start_line = int(args.start_line)
    start_mailbox = int(args.start_mailbox)
    start_email = int(args.start_email)
    timeout = float(args.timeout)
    port = args.port
    use_ssl = args.ssl
    mark_as_read = args.mark_as_read
    login_only = args.login_only
    email_parts = args.parts
    output_dir = args.output_dir
    verbosity_level = int(args.verbosity_level)

    socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

    if credentials_file:
        batch_scrape(
            file=credentials_file,
            host=host,
            port=port,
            use_ssl=use_ssl,
            login_only=login_only,
            file_delimiter=file_delimiter,
            start_line=start_line,
            try_common_hosts=try_common_hosts,
            mark_as_read=mark_as_read,
            email_parts=email_parts,
            output_dir=output_dir,
            timeout=timeout,
            verbosity_level=verbosity_level
        )
    else:
        try:
            server_connection = server_login(
                user_or_email_or_combo=username,
                password=password,
                host=host,
                port=port,
                use_ssl=use_ssl,
                try_common_hosts=try_common_hosts,
                timeout=timeout
            )

            scrape_emails(
                server=server_connection,
                mark_as_read=mark_as_read,
                email_parts=email_parts,
                start_mailbox=start_mailbox,
                start_email=start_email,
                output_dir=output_dir,
                verbosity_level=verbosity_level
            )
        except email_scraper_errors as error:
            sys.stderr.write(str(error) + "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stdout.write("\nQuitting...\n")
    sys.stdout.write("Finished in {} seconds\n".format(round(time.time() - start_time, 3)))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Some people here are a bit allergic to phrases like "I omitted X[, because of Y]". Maybe you should mention that those two functions can be found in your Github repository, and that you don't want to have them reviewed. If they should be included in the review, also add their source code to the question.

Comment: @AlexV Thanks for the welcome. I omitted those functions because I thought the code would be just too long, so I would rather have people focus on the provided code. I'll edit the question to better reflect that.

Comment: Don't worry about long pieces of code, we can handle long.

Comment: You could use some shorter functions though, wow.

Answer (score 1):

## [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations

You've got a lot of function declarations where you put the arguments on multiple lines to make then more obvious, like this:

```
def _download_email_attachments(
        server: Union[imaplib.IMAP4, imaplib.IMAP4_SSL],
        email_number: str,
        output_dir: Optional[str] = "attachments"
):
```

Personally, I would follow PEP 8's recommendation and use an alignment with the opening delimiter:

```
def _download_email_attachments(server: Union[imaplib.IMAP4, imaplib.IMAP4_SSL],
                                email_number: str,
                                output_dir: Optional[str] = "attachments"):
```

The same goes for function calls. Also, since you are using type hinting, make sure you hint the type of the return value of the function:

```
                                output_dir: Optional[str] = "attachments"): -> MyType
```

For function declarations like this:

```
def _count_lines(
        filename: str
):
```

The expansion onto the next line is unnecessary, just use `def _count_lines(filename: str): -> MyType`.

Your class `server_error` does not follow PEP 8 recommendation of the `CapWords` convention. It's commonly used in the vast majority of scripts and for almost every exception I've ever seen. You should change the name to `ServerError`.

---

## General stuff

- Your program is heavily commented which is good for future developers to know what's going on.
- I don't know the slightest thing about mail protocols, but I really hope your program works the way it is supposed to :)

The first big thing I see is that you don't have a docstring. To me, as a developer, it's not immediately evident what the program does when I view the source code. Also, it's not great for IDEs that provide introspection into modules based on its docstring.

There are a lot of spots where I see things like this:

```
host = server.host

if output_dir is None:
    output_dir = host
```

In that particular function, `host` is never used again. In situations like those, it's not necessary to declare a reference only to have it assigned to another variable - at that point you've got a reference chain two deep, which is unnecessary. I understand you may be doing it for readability, but there's some point where you need to ask yourself if things like that are really necessary.

In this `try`/`except`:

```
        except PermissionError:
            raise PermissionError("Could not create {}, invalid permissions".format(mailbox_output_directory))
```

You should instead use:

```
        except PermissionError as e:
            raise PermissionError("Could not create {}, invalid permissions".format(mailbox_output_directory)) from e
```

It's just to provide more context in exceptions. If you want to find out a bit more about `raise ... from`, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752395/python-raise-from-usage) is useful.

I noticed a lot of times you used `sys.stdout.write` and `sys.stderr.write`. Since you're in Python 3, you could simply use:

```
print(...)                    # For sys.stdout, since that is the default
print(..., file=sys.stderr)   # For sys.stderr, using the file kwarg
```

Finally, in your `__name__`/`"__main__"`, it looks like you use `time.time()` to time the execution of the script. As far as I am aware, it is recommended to `time.process_time()` or `time.perf_counter()` depending on how long your script takes to run. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/pythons-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy) for a bit more information.

---

If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree with all your PEP8 related recommendations. The reason I aligned all the function arguments the way I did is that I use tabs instead of spaces so I can't always align them properly. I guess the solution is to use spaces as I've also had additional alignment problems. I used `camel_case` for the exception classes as I have one named `connection_error` and if I converted it to `CapsCase` then it would shadow a built-in exception. Should I come up with a different name for that and convert them to CapsCase or can I keep them camel_case? (1/2) ...

Comment: ... (2/2) Instead of a docstring I have a README file inside the github repository. There you can find out what the program does as well as other info. I don't expect this file to be available without the README, but I can see the value in having a docstring when using an IDE. I realise that this was an error on my part for not including all the files directly in the question. All the other remarks in the general part are valid :)

Comment: @choket Hi, sorry for the late response. You should probably convert that exception to `CapsCase` and rename it to something a bit more specific (if it shadows a built-in it's probably not specific enough). And as for the README, I think that's acceptable as an alternative to a docstring. It's completely up to you.